# How to control browser in focus?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm playing around with C# webdriver and trying to figure out how to control which browser is in focus.

This is basicly what i want do

```
        driver = StartBrowser();
        driver1 = StartBrowser();
```

and then switch back to driver, but i can't get it working.

I know it's prob really simple but i still can't get it working :).

This is what i tried different versions of:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.CurrentWindowHandle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwitchTo` is to change the context of a single driver (browser). This is used when you have frames or pop up windows and you want to tell selenium where to look for elements.

If you declare two separate driver instances (per your example) then you will have two independent browser instances where each will have its own context to search. There is logically no reason to switch between them because you can search each browser by using the corresponding driver variable.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought but if I initiate driver and then driver1 as per my example. And then attempt to click around and send keys to driver i get "Element not displayed error"

But if i just reverse the initiation so the driver i want to work with is the last one initiated there's no problems.

Comment: I wrote a quick example and it works for me, so there is a couple things you can try. 1) Try the same setup but with different pages, this will tell you if its a timing issue (which Selenium is notorious for) 2) Try with different browsers. Also make sure you are using the latest version of Selenium, version 2.4.0 was not a good release and 2.5.0 fixed some important bugs. EDIT: Forgot to mention, since you get an element not displayed error that means the driver is successfully searching its elements

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the response. Ill try to see what happens if i run the examples as you said.

Comment: I got it working now... thanks, don't know what the problem was before. But i made a test on a different site just clicking around and there was no problems. so thanks for the answer